# How to append column values to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dataframe, numpy

I have a numpy array arr:

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [4., 2., 1.],
       [1., 2., 0.]])
```

Also I have pandas dataframe df:

```
col1   col2
a       2
b       7
c       10
```

I want to append values from col2 to array to get this result:

```
array([[1., 2., 3., 2.],
       [4., 2., 1., 7.],
       [1., 2., 0., 10.]])
```

this didn't work
arr[:, :-1] = df["col2"]

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hstack` works, another way is this:

```
from numpy import array, c_
from pandas import DataFrame

arr = array([
    [1., 2., 3.],
    [4., 2., 1.],
    [1., 2., 0.]
])

df = DataFrame([
    ['a', 2], 
    ['b', 7], 
    ['c', 10]
], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

arr = c_[arr, df['col2']]
print(arr)
```

Result:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  2.]
 [ 4.  2.  1.  7.]
 [ 1.  2.  0. 10.]]
```

I like the brevity and simplicity of `c_[arr, df['col2']]`, but of course it's not exactly descriptive, so only people that are aware of it will get its meaning https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.hstack`:

```
np.hstack([arr, df.col2.to_frame()])
```

You need to make sure both of them have the same shape, that's why the `to_frame` part. You could also just add another axis directly `df.col2[:, None]`.